# Show E[E(X|Y)]=E[X]

Tags: conditional-expectation

Show E[E(X|Y)]=E[X]

Now if X and Y are independent then it is very straightforward as E(X|Y)]=E[X].
However is there a better explanation to this ? Can we prove this mathematically ?

What if X and Y are not independent ? Will it hold ?

Comment: You can try to show it for discrete variables X and Y first. Bayes rule may come handy.

Comment: E(X|Y) is a fixed value, what you mean the expected value of that?

Comment: E(X|Y) is not always a fixed value. It can be a function of y too! I mean using the properties of conditional expectation, how can we prove it ?

Comment: @Aviral: So, in the case that $Y$ is a discrete random variable, here's the start: $$E[E[X|Y]] = \sum_y E[X|Y=y]p(Y=y) = \sum_y \big(xp_{X|Y}(x|y)\big) p_Y(y).$$

Comment: "Show E[E(X|Y)]=E[X]" Isn't this direct from the definition of E(X|Y)? What is this definition, already?

Comment: @cxz "E(X|Y) is a fixed value, what you mean the expected value of that?" Actually E(X|Y) is a random variable, by definition.

Comment: @Ted The identity in your comment might lack an integral sign.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).
First, note that

$$E[X|Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{X|Y}(x|y)xdx\tag{1}$$

where $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is the conditional probability density function. Then note that

$$E[E[X|Y]]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E[X|Y=y]\;p_Y(y)dy\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives

$$\begin{align}E[E[X|Y]]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{X|Y}(x|y)p_Y(y)x\,dxdy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{XY}(x,y)\,dy\,dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp_X(x)dx\\&=E[X]\tag{3}\end{align}$$

where I've used $p_{X|Y}(x|y)p_Y(y)=p_{XY}(x,y)$, and $p_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{XY}(x,y)dy$.

Comment: It is odd to place the notion of conditional PDF at the center of everything related to conditional expectations. It is not. To begin with, it may not exist, just like ordinary PDFs may not exist and are not the rigorous way to define ordinary expectations.

Comment: The proof for the general case is in the Wikipedia article linked above. Direct link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case

Comment: @Did: Thanks for your feedback; I guess that most engineers are taught expectations in that way (based on PDFs), so that's the way I'm used to thinking about them. It would be great if someone else posted a more rigorous answer.

Comment: @MattL. In the present case there is no real need since the thing is (textbook stuff and) explained in tons of places, including on this very site.